# Removing public form laravel url?

Tags: .htaccess, laravel

I am removing public from laravel url by using .htaccess i am writing the code on my htaceess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

htacces file is in the root of laravel and my mode_rewrite also enable 
after that i am getting error `Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.` but i can still get welcome page by `http://localhost/laravel/public/` please solve my issue

Answer (score 2):

Your web server configuration is wrong. You should point your web server to a `public` directory.

For example, if you're using Apache, you should set up it like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myapp.localhost.com
  DocumentRoot "/home/vagrant/projects/myapp/public"
  <Directory "/home/vagrant/projects/myapp/public">
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In XAMMP, MAMP, OpenServer etc. you need just to change root directory to Laravel's public directory.

Also, don't forget to restart your web server to make everything work.

Comment: If you've made any changes in .htaccess or index.php, undo all changes. Did you restart web server?